# where and how to read results of ebextensions execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I added `.ebextensions/start.config` file to the root folder of my WAR bundle (as [suggested by AWS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)), deployed it to Elastic Beanstalk, but nothing happened. Where in the EC2 instance can I see log of this file processing? Or maybe I can see this information in TAIL report of EBT?

Comment: I implemented retrieval of such logs in [jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin/index.html) in an automated way, right after deployment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a Linux 32 bits Tomcat 7 container, I was able to find logs at:  `/var/log/eb-tools.log`, where I was able to see which of my commands failed.

Comment: This answer appears to be obsolete now. @SamuelJack's answer of looking at the log file at this path worked for me: /var/log/cfn-init.log

Answer (score 23):

Snapshot the Logs for your Elastic Beanstalk environment through the online console.

When you view the logs, search for a section beginning "cfn-init.log".

In that section you'll see entries like

```
2013-08-30 10:25:13,517 [INFO] Command 01-ec2setcomputername-enable succeeded
2013-08-30 10:25:24,516 [INFO] Command 02-install-server-monitor succeeded
2013-08-30 10:25:30,115 [INFO] Command 03-install-agent succeeded
```

where 01-ec2setcomputername-enable, etc. are the names of the commands in my .config file. If the command fails, you should see the error message here too.

Comment: And you can see the output of these commands in "cfn-init-cmd.log" file specified by "Command Output" term ;

Answer (score 17):

You can tail some logs in the web UI to see whether your `.ebextensions` worked ([via Elastic Beanstalk → view an environment → Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html)). You should see a success or fail message for each command you define. (For example, for a command named `01_setup` you'll see a message like `command 01_setup succeeded`.)

#### Viewing command output

Although the log snapshot will show that a command failed, it won't show the command output:

```
[ERROR] Command 01_setup (setup.cmd) failed
[ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_server: Command 01_setup failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
   <irrelevant traceback>
```

You can connect to the underlying EC2 server and view the command output in the `cfn-init-cmd.log` file (that's `c:\cfn\log\cfn-init-cmd.log` in Windows, or `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` in Linux). This provides more useful information:

```
[INFO] Running command "setup.cmd"
[INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
[INFO]  'setup.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[INFO]  operable program or batch file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Exited with error code 1
```

For help connecting to an EC2 instance, see [Windows instructions](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1MVS5K9DFA275/Connecting-to-Amazon-EC2-Instances-from-the-AWS-Toolkit-for-Visual-Studio).

#### Further troubleshooting

The command output also lets you run arbitrary commands to figure out what's going on. For example, which directory are the commands being executed in?

Here's the `.ebextensions` file:

```
container_commands:
  where_am_i:
    command: dir
```

And here's the output in `cfn-init-cmd.log`:

```
[INFO] Running command "dir"
[INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
[INFO]   Volume in drive C has no label.
[INFO]   Volume Serial Number is 12A7-BAEB
[INFO]  
[INFO]   Directory of C:\inetpub\wwwroot
[INFO]  
[INFO]  05/29/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          .
[INFO]  05/29/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
[INFO]  05/29/2015  05:42 PM    <DIR>          .ebextensions
[INFO]  05/29/2015  05:31 PM    <DIR>          bin
[INFO]  05/28/2015  05:20 PM               106 Global.asax
[INFO]  05/28/2015  05:20 PM               498 packages.config
[INFO]  05/28/2015  05:20 PM             2,054 README.md
[INFO]  05/29/2015  06:56 PM             3,064 Web.config
[INFO]                 4 File(s)          5,722 bytes
[INFO]                 4 Dir(s)   4,553,273,344 bytes free
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 8):

For Windows, the log file that contains your custom ebextension output is not part of the EB logs that you get via the EB console "request logs" command. But, you can easily add that log file to the bundle via this file command in an .ebextension file:

```
files:
  "C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\ElasticBeanstalk\\config\\taillogs.d\\cfn-init-cmd.conf" :
    content: |
      c:\cfn\log\cfn-init-cmd.log
```

All it does is create a new config file (cfn-init-cmd.conf) with the name of the log file (cfn-init-cmd.log) that you want added to the log bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the logs by ssh into ec2 and check logs.
For this, from the root folder execute:

```
cat /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log
```

Answer (score 0):

install and configure the [eb cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html) than:

```
 eb logs development
```