# Referencing env variables from Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions config files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it posssible to reference the PARAM1 / PARAM2 etc.. container environment properties from the .ebextensions config files. If so, how? I tried $PARAM1 but it seemed to be an empty value.

I want to set the hostname on startup to contain DEV, QA or PROD, which I pass to my container via the PARAM1 environment variable.

```
commands:
  01-set-correct-hostname:
    command: hostname myappname{$PARAM1}.com
```

Comment: Why is there still no answer for this?!?!? Below only tells you how to do it with `contaienr_comands` not `commands`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out you can only do this in the `container_commands` section, not the `commands` section.

This works:

```
container_commands:
  01-set-correct-hostname:
    command: "hostname myappname{$PARAM1}.com"
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands for more details.

Comment: That link doesn't mention anything about using environment variables in container commands.

Comment: @Nate Read the Container_Commands section, where it says "They also have access to environment variables such as your AWS security credentials."

Comment: Won't you run into hostname problems if your beanstalk configuration is spawning multiple ec2 instances?

Comment: does this work for regular `commands:`? My testing indicates not.

Comment: @PeterEhrlich, per the answer, this *only* works on container_commands.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore since these params are no longer environment variables but application variables instead.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what worked for me.  I tried the accepted approach and it did not produce the desired result (curly braces were included in the output). Troubleshooting commands that are executed from a .config file when uploading to Elastic Beanstalk is also a bit of a challenge (or I just don't know exactly where to look).

AWS Environment:

- Type - Elastic Beanstalk
- Platform - 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running PHP 5.6

Elastic Beanstalk Environment Properties (Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Environment Properties):

- Property Name - HELLO_VARIABLE
- Property Value - test

Sample .config File included in the .ebextensions folder in the deployment artifact:

```
container_commands:
  0_test-variable:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: "touch ${HELLO_VARIABLE}_0_.txt"
  1_test-variable:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: "touch {$HELLO_VARIABLE}_1_.txt"
  2_test-variable:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: "touch $HELLO_VARIABLE_2_.txt"
```

After the artifact has been deployed using Elastic Beanstalk the /tmp directory within an EC2 instance will contain the following files (note curly braces and position of $):

- *touch ${HELLO_VARIABLE}_0_.txt* creates */tmp/test_0_.txt*
- *touch {$HELLO_VARIABLE}_1_.txt* creates */tmp/{test}_1_.txt*
- *touch $HELLO_VARIABLE_2_.txt* creates */tmp/.txt*

Comment: The reason you don't see your command output in the log files is because EB is only including specific log files. But, you can add the cfn-init-cmd.log to the bundle. I explain it here for Windows, but you should be able to figure out how to change it for Linux.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/37189606/674488

Comment: for troubleshooting look in  /var/log/eb-activity.log

Answer (score 8):

To make the environment variables available at the commands stage I parse them into a bash sourceable file.

000001.envvars.config

```
...
commands:
  000001_envvars_to_bash_source_file:
    command: |
      # source our elastic beanstalk environment variables
      /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment|perl -ne "/^\w/ or next; s/: /=/; print qq|\$_|" > /var/tmp/envvars
      chmod 400 /var/tmp/envvars
...
```

Then I use:-

```
source /var/tmp/envvars
```

in subsequent commands.

Answer (score 8):

Accepted answer is quite outdated.

Now you can use `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` file which is already a shell script ready to be sourced:

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: |
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

container_commands:
  01_run_composer:
  command: |
    composer.phar install --no-scripts --no-dev  # already has user-specified env variables
```

---

**Update:**

After some deeper investigation turns out that `container_commands:` include your environment variables, but `commands:` not.