# Accessing environment variables in AWS Beanstalk ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to access an environment variable that I have defined in the AWS Beanstalk configuration. I need to access it within a config file in `.ebextensions` *or* in a file that is copied in place in a config file. I have tried the following:

```
container_commands:
  update_nginx_config:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/files/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

And in my `nginx.conf` file, I have tried to access `$MYVAR`, `${MYVAR}` and `{$MYVAR}`, some of which was suggested [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=529504) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585898/referencing-env-variables-from-elastic-beanstalk-ebextensions-config-files) (the latter being directly within a config file).

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      $MYVAR ${MYVAR} {$MYVAR}
```

This does not work either. In all cases, the variable names are just output such as `$MYVAR`, so Beanstalk does not recognize my variables. I found the below in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) about `container_commands`:

> They also have access to environment variables such as your AWS
>   security credentials.

This is great, but it does not say *how*.

How can I access an environment variable with ebextensions, be it within a config file itself or in a separate file that is copied in place?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I reached out to the Amazon technical support for an answer to this question, and here is their reply:

---

> Unfortunately the variables are not available in ebextensions
>   directly. The best option to do that is by creating a script that then
>   is run from container commands like this:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/setup.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      # Commands that will be run on container_commmands
      # Here the container variables will be visible as environment variables.

container_commands:
  set_up:
    command: /home/ec2-user/setup.sh
```

---

So, if you create a shell script and invoke it via a container command, then you will have access to environment variables within your shell script as follows: `$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`. I have tested this, and it works.

If you're having issues running a script as root and not being able to read the configured environment variables, try adding the following to the top of your script.

```
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
```

Depending on your use case, you might have to change your approach a bit (at least I did), but it is a working solution. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 46):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47817647/2246559

You can use the GetOptionSetting function described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html

For instance, if you were setting the `worker_processes` variable, it could look like:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      worker_processes `{"Fn::GetOptionSetting": {"Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment", "OptionName": "MYVAR"}}`;
```

Note the backticks `` in the function call.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works. If the YAML format complains, you might need to surround the backticks. foo: `'\`{...}\`'`

Answer (score 10):

In case you're using the value directly in a container command, the `get-config` script that comes with the instance can help.

Example :

```
20_install_certs:
  command: |
    MY_VAR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k MY_VAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit different use-case and be only for debugging purposes.

You can access the environment variables via

```
$ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html

Only works for Linux environments I think!