# How to access environment variables in AWS Beanstalk ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to access an environment variable which i defined in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration. I need to access it within a config file in `.ebextensions` or in a file that is shared below. I have tried the following:

```
packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    user: root
    group: root

    content: |
      [/var/log/httpd/error_log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-$APP_ENV/var/log/httpd/error_log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/httpd/error_log*

      [/var/log/httpd/access_log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-$APP_ENV/var/log/httpd/access_log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/httpd/access_log*

# commands:
  "01":
    command: systemctl enable awslogsd.service
  "02":
    command: systemctl restart awslogsd
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423608/accessing-environment-variables-in-aws-beanstalk-ebextensions#:~:text=I%20reached%20out%20to%20the%20Amazon%20technical%20support%20for%20an%20answer%20to%20this%20question%2C%20and%20here%20is%20their%20reply%3A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423608/accessing-environment-variables-in-aws-beanstalk-ebextensions#:%7E:text=I%20reached%20out%20to%20the%20Amazon%20technical%20support%20for%20an%20answer%20to%20this%20question%2C%20and%20here%20is%20their%20reply%3A)
with this answer i change the commands to container_commands but its not working