# Automatic launch of Celery on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've read some of the previous threads on how to do this, but it appears the script given in those threads doesn't work anymore.

I know I need a `celery.config` file to be placed in my `.ebextensions` directory. That file needs to configure celery and then run `supervisord` on celery to start it as a daemon. Has anyone had luck doing this in the past 6 months or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem really took so many of my time but it finally worked.
See my answer in this question, I've asked with reputation bounty but no one answered, after solving it I've added my own answer.

[How to run celery worker on elastic beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566456/how-to-run-a-celery-worker-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/39302056#39302056)

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks, it seems to be pretty similar to the script I found, but you explained it much better. Maybe this question can finally be a resource for people.

Comment: I hope it works for you either. You can write if it doesn't work.

Comment: It does work, I made sure to test it before replying here.

Comment: Good then I'm happy to help you :)