# Echo a string from ebextension script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Windows instance of aws Elastic Beanstalk. I want to echo a text from the script inside .ebextensions folder and be able to see it in the deployment logs. Here is what I have:

```
container_commands:
  0100_execute_only_in_dev:
    command: echo "The_man_in_the_high_castle"
```

The deployment is successful but when I requested logs for the EC2 instance, there is no text echo'ed.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files:
  "C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\ElasticBeanstalk\\config\\taillogs.d\\cfn-init-cmd.conf" :
    content: |
      c:\cfn\log\cfn-init-cmd.log
container_commands:
  0109_cmd:
    command: "echo show this: %My_Env%"
```

In the end, the above worked for me.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37189606/192727 helped a lot